# Function that change in predictable direction with its argument

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

What do you call a function that changes in predictable direction when its argument changes? For example:

$$
f(x_1) \ge f(x_2) \text{ if } x_1 \ge x_2 \\
g(x_1) \le g(x_2) \text{ if } x_1 \ge x_2
$$

I'm working on a class of problem that requires some functions to have these properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These functions are called monotonically increasing or decreasing.

If the property is $f(x)>f(y)$ for $x>y$ that function is called strictly increasing.

---

edit: Read more about this on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function).

Answer (score 1):

The example looks like **increasing** and **decreasing** function to me.